# If detail section repeat a field value then keep final one and suppress remaining

Tags: crystal-reports-8.5

**If detail section repeat a field value then keep final one and suppress remaining (crystal report 8.5)**

Comment: suppress-  {field}= previous {field}- result will be suppress all repeated raws

Comment: can you show us how you wish your data to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your question, but could you do a suppress on the section?

Click on Suppress(no drill down), click on X+2:

```
Not OnLastRecord
```